# cardinality of a set in diophantine geometry

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $a >0$ a real number. I want to compute the cardinality of the set :

$$ \lbrace x \in \mathbb{Q}^{*} \; | \; |x| \leq a \; \text{and } \; v_p(x) \geq 0,\; \forall p \in \mathcal{P} \rbrace $$

For context, this set appears when I consider an Archimedean Arakelov divisor, of the form $D = \ln(a) ( \infty)$ on $\mathrm{spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.
And we have :
$$ H^0(D) = \lbrace x \in \mathbb{Q}^{*} \; | \; (x) + D \geq 0 \rbrace $$

Comment: If $v_p (x) \geq 0$ for all primes, don't you necessarily have $x \in \mathbb{Z}^*$? If so you would have $2 \operatorname{floor} (a) $

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace That's right, $x$ would have to be a non-zero integer, and so the bound is correct.

Comment: Thanks for answers ! Have a nice day :)